# Perform a search and get all of the matches

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Let's have this example, the question is: "How many times Anne has Science with any commentary"? (answer: `2` times).

```
    A         B         C       D
1   Name    Gender  Subject Commentary
2   Anne    Female  Maths   
3   Anne    Female  English 
4   Anne    Female  Science whatever...
5   Anne    Female  Maths   
6   Anne    Female  English 
7   Anne    Female  Science blah, blah 
8   Kath    Female  Maths   
9   Kath    Female  English 
10  Kath    Female  Science 
11  Tony    Male    Maths   etc...
12  Tony    Male    English 
13  Tony    Male    Science blah, blah
```

I solved it using COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A1:A13,"Anne",D1:D13,"*")
```

But now I need to search all of the Anne+Science commentaries and retrieve them concatenated in a result cell, this way: "whatever....blah, blah."

How can do it?
If there is no way to do it using formulas, how using VBA?

Comment: @pnuts answer will do it without any VBA. With VBA you can either use a simple range iteration and concatenate  string based on the criteria (Dick's answer does this), or use `AutoFilter` and concatenate the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` in column D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function Commentary(rSource As Range, sName As String, sSubject As String) As String

    Dim vaSource As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim aOutput() As String

    vaSource = rSource.Value

    For i = LBound(vaSource, 1) To UBound(vaSource, 1)
        If vaSource(i, 1) Like sName And vaSource(i, 3) Like sSubject Then
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve aOutput(1 To lCnt)
            aOutput(lCnt) = vaSource(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i

    Commentary = Join(aOutput, "|")

End Function
```

Used like

```
=Commentary(A1:D13,"Anne","Science")
```

Comment: Does this work with a range of another sheet?:  I'm getting problems with =Commentary(Sheet2!A1:D49,"*",M3)

Comment: Yes, it will work on other sheets. I just changed the "=" to "Like" so that you can use an asterisk. It wouldn't work with an asterisk as previously written.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a PivotTable and concatenate the results there as shown:

[image: SO19503989 example]

*Edit*

I should have explained, if there are many entries, use `=I6&", "&F7` in I7, copy down to suit and select the last in the series.